# The entry (Database) has already been added

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, deployment, azure-sql-database

I have two applications that are sharing the same database that is an `API` and an `MVC5` app. Both run well on localhost but on deployment to my Azure account i get this error

```
 Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration
             file required to service this request. Please review the
             specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The entry 'XlabDatabase' has already been added.

Source Error:

 An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings
 for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons)
```

I have taken steps to even rename the database but on deployment i use the same remote string

here is my MVC app connectionstring

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="XlabDatabase_acc" providerName="System.Data.SQLClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;App=EntityFramework" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Here's my MVC Context

```
    public virtual DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AnnualReport> AnnualReports { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<MonthlyReport> MonthlyReports { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<WeekReport> WeekReports { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<AnnualReport>().HasKey<int>(x => x.AnnualReportID);
        builder.Entity<MonthlyReport>().HasKey<int>(x => x.MonthlyReportID);
        builder.Entity<WeekReport>().HasKey<int>(x => x.ReportID);

    }
```

Here's my API connection string

```
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="XlabDatabase" providerName="System.Data.SQLClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Here's my API context

```
 public virtual DbSet<Customers> Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Salesman> Salesman { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Route> Route { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Purchase> Purchase { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Products> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Assets> Assets { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<WeekReports> WKReports { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<MonthlyReports> MONReports { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AnnualReports> ANNReports { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Accounts> Accounts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<LoadingOrder> LoadingOrder { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        builder.Entity<LoadingOrder>().HasRequired(c => c.Salesman).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim").HasKey<Int32>(r => r.Id);
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin").HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role").HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        builder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User").HasKey(r => new{ r.IDNumber, r.UserName});
        builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("User").HasKey<string>(r => r.UserName);
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole").HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });

    }
```

I have deployed the two applications into two different Virtual Applications and Directories.

**UPDATE**

This is how i deploy the two applications they share the same connection string

[image]

I have also added the `Initial Catalog` to the connection strings 
`XLAB`

Comment: You deployed  MVC App and the API to Azure and using this connection string to connect to the db. First of all this needs to change , you need to connect to a azure sql/on-premise sql db(if you have necessary infrastructure setup). The current connection string won't work when you move apps to azure(either App service or VM) Second I do not see the "Initial Catalog" (Database name) in the connection string, is it there in your original code?

Comment: I have added the Initial Catalog but nothing changed. As for the Connection string i have updated my question with an image of how i deploy both applications using the same connection string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the connection string, after the `<providers>` and before the first `<add....>` node, add a `<clear />` node.

Comment: What does this mean? I don't see "providers" anywhere.

Comment: On the API's connection string.   <connectionStrings>
     <add name="XlabDatabase" providerName="System.Data.SQLClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" />
  </connectionStrings>